# Print file name,Modified Date and Size with Header

Tags: bash, shell, centos, rhel

How do I  print file size, file name and modified date with header.Till now I have come up with:

```
find . -regex '.*\.csv' -execdir stat --printf '%n,%y,%s' {} \;
```

How to add header and do not print path rather only filename?

```
eg
File Name,Modified Date
Apple,2015-01-05 12:13
```

Comment: You choice of stat is good. Use something like: **stat -c "%y  %8s  %n" -- * | cut -c 1-19,36- | sort -nr**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this with GNU find:

```
echo "File Name,Modified Date"; find . -name '*.csv' -printf "%f,%TY-%Tm-%Td %TI:%TM\n"
```

Comment: can you add how this command works. specially the printf part and how does it differ from mine --print and use of exec for each file.

Comment: Your command runs `stat` for every found file. This is not necessary because GNU find's builtin -printf can show file's last modification time (with %T) and format it as you want. Please see find's manpage section `-printf format` with subsections %Tk and %Ak.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
fd "<regex>" "<dir>" --exec find {} -printf "%T@ %Td-%Tb-%TY %TT %p\n" |
 sort -n | cut -d " " -f 2-
```

Comment: What is the `fd` command?

Comment: What @JeffSchaller wrote!  Is it be a typo ? And should we just read *find* instead ?

Comment: Probably [this](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd). It’s not clear to me whether combining `fd` and `find` is significantly better than using `find` directly...